# Share a Azure Shared Image gallery with a management group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Thanks in Advance. I am new to Azure cloud and I have below setup in my Azure cloud

Subscription 1:

- Created a VM image with packer called image 1.
- Created a new shared image gallery.
- uploaded the packer VM image(image 1) to the new Shared image gallery.

I also have more subscriptions like subscription 2 to subscription 10 and all these subscriptions are under a management group called "dev" and under the same tenant called "company".

**Question:** How can I automatically share the Shared image gallery images with all subscriptions? Also can I share the shared image gallery with the management group?

A how-to steps will be more useful here as I don't see a valid document from MS on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Shared Image Gallery you can share your images to different users, service principals, or AD groups within and outside your organization.
Shared Image Galleries let you share images using Azure RBAC. You can use Azure RBAC to share images within your tenant, and even to individuals outside of your tenant
We can give share access at the image gallery level

1. On the page for your new image gallery, in the menu on the left, select Access control (IAM).
2. Under Add a role assignment, select Add. The Add a role assignment pane will open.
3. Under Role, select Reader.
4. Under assign access to, leave the default of Azure AD user, group, or service principal.
5. Under Select, type in the email address of the person that you would like to invite.
6. If the user is outside of your organization, you will see the message This user will be sent an email that enables them to collaborate with Microsoft. Select the user with the email address and then click Save.

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-images-portal#share-the-gallery)

[Shared Image Galleries overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/shared-image-galleries)